# why my bubble sort does not function propertly?

Tags: python, python-3.x

i'm trying to use an optimized way of a bubble sort using the (while True ..loop) but can't see why it still prints out [5, 6, -5, 2, 7, 8, 9]

```
def tree_bulle(l):
  n=len(l)
  while True :
    new_tour=False
    for i in range(n-1):
      if l[i]>l[i+1]:
         l[i],l[i+1]=l[i+1],l[i]
         new_tour=True
      n-=1  
    if new_tour==False or n==0:
      break


list=[5,8,6,-5,2,7,9]
tree_bulle(list)
print(list)
```

Comment: Check your logic / indentation for the `n -= 1` line...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is extra indent in `n-=1`. So when the `for` circulation execute first time, the n will get smaller. so the next time, the while circulation will only execute `for i in range(2-1)`, then you code can not sort the remain elements anymore.

change your code to:

```
def tree_bulle(l):
  n=len(l)
  while True :
    new_tour=False
    for i in range(n-1):
      if l[i]>l[i+1]:
         l[i],l[i+1]=l[i+1],l[i]
         new_tour=True
    n-=1  # n is changed after the for circulation
    if new_tour==False or n==0:
      break


list=[5,8,6,-5,2,7,9]
tree_bulle(list)
print(list)
```

Comment: Hi sorry for my bitter comment earlier , but could you please add some context as I am also interested